# struggling with wrapfig2

Tags: wrapfig2

I can't get what I want with the `wrapfig2` package.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}%pour mettre des figures à côté de texte
\usepackage{babel}%francisation
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}%pour les graphiques et bien d'autres choses


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Exemple de résolution d'inéquation}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
        \draw[thick,->] (-0.7,0) -- (3.9,0) node[right] {\small $x$};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-0.9) -- (0,3.9) node[above] {\small $y$};
        \clip (-0.7,-0.9) rectangle (3.9,3.9);
        \draw[help lines] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
        \node[anchor=base,fill=white] at (3,-0.6) {\small $3$};
        \node[anchor=base,fill=white] at (2,-0.6) {\small $2$};
        \node[anchor=base,fill=white] at (1,-0.6) {\small $1$};
        \draw[thick] (0.1,1) -- (-0.1,1) node[left,fill=white] {\small $1$};
        \draw[thick] (0.1,2) -- (-0.1,2) node[left,fill=white] {\small $2$};
        \draw[thick] (0.1,3) -- (-0.1,3) node[left,fill=white] {\small $3$};
        \draw[thick] (-3,0.1) -- (-3,-0.1);
        \draw[thick] (-2,0.1) -- (-2,-0.1);
        \draw[thick] (-1,0.1) -- (-1,-0.1);
        \draw[thick] (3,0.1) -- (3,-0.1);
        \draw[thick] (2,0.1) -- (2,-0.1);
        \draw[thick] (1,0.1) -- (1,-0.1);
        \node[blue] at (3.6,1.5) {\small $f_3$};
        \node[above] at (1.333,0) {\small $\alpha$};
        \node[left] at (0,-0.385) {\small $\beta$};
        \draw[dotted] (0,-0.385) -| (1.333,0);
        \draw[very thick,blue,domain=1:4,samples=100] plot (\x,{(\x-2)*sqrt(\x-1)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
En prenant par exemple la fonction $f_3$ de l'exercice précédent, la représentation graphique à l'ordinateur met en évidence un minimum atteint en $\alpha\in[1,2]$ et dont on pourrait donner une valeur décimale approchée en zoomant un peu.  

\bigskip
Mais seule l'étude de la dérivée et la construction du tableau de variations nous permettent de donner la valeur exacte de ce minimum, à savoir $\beta=-2\sqrt{3}/9$, et la valeur en laquelle il est atteint, à savoir $\alpha=4/3$, ainsi que de vérifier qu'il n'y a pas de variation erratique en dehors de la zone tracée.

\end{document}
```

And here is what I get:
[image]

As you can see, the figure is two down. I tried many things, including the star version of the environment, but I was unsuccessful.

And then, I noticed that if I comment the line `\textbf{Exemple de résolution d'inéquation}`, the spacing is good, or at least better:
[image]

So I don't understand. I guess I don't use the environment correctly.
So what should I do to have a correct alignment and keep my title?

Comment: wrapfigure are very difficult beasts has they have to change the shape of the surrouding paragraph. Imho the easiest is normally to change the bounding box of the content. E.g. in your case you could try `\path[use as bounding box](-0.7,-0.9) rectangle (3.9,3.4);`

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer But where exactly should I add this line? In my real file (unlike in this MWE), the TikZ figure is not in the file but called with an input in the main file

Comment: Wrapfig enulates fgivure [h] by adding an `\intextsep` gap above and below,  but not at the top of the page.  You can use `\intextsep=0pt` inside a group, or add `\vspace{-\intextsep}` inside the wrapfigure.

Comment: Thank you both. It works fine